# Why is Encoding.ASCII class not available for Windows Store apps?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm using the Encoding.ASCII class in my WinForms app. Now I need to convert that into a Windows Store app. The problem is, the ASCII class is missing!

```
using System.Text;
```

Here is the assembly and in other types the System.Text.ASCII class is available but not in this one.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN Forums Post 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-TT/winappswithcsharp/thread/8a844a21-39cf-4134-8010-53bea1080852):

> The suggestion is to use UTF8 encoding instead which is compatible with ASCII.

From [MSDN Forums Post 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1969d493-552d-4ed3-ac57-84ad318cbe69):

> You should be able to use UTF8 encoding where you used ASCIIEncoding.  UTF8 is a superset and should be compatible.

Comment: This should be marked as an answer. So use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8